# How to add active class in the <li> every time the user scroll on a certain section using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a code that will active the anchored link everytime I scroll but instead of the a href to be active I want the li before the link here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.left-nav a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.left-nav a li').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");

        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any one can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Within `$('.left-nav a').each(function () {` you need to traverse up to the `li`

Store the parent `li`

```
var currLink = $(this);
var currParent = $(this).closest('li');
```

and replace `currLink.addClass` and `currLink.removeClass` with `currParent.addClass` and `currParent.removeClass`